# What is the solution to support uploads to the S3 from AmazonS3Client with slower internet connections in android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am working on a Android project where I need to upload say 20 images at a time to S3 using AWS S3 client in android I am facing issues with the slower internet connection.

when there is a slower internet connection then the image upload fails every time please suggest the solution.

This is the function I am using for uploading files to S3

```
fun uploadFile(file: File, accessKey:String, secretKey:String, bucketName: String, region:String, distributionUrl: String): String{
    val clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration()
    clientConfiguration.connectionTimeout = 60000
    clientConfiguration.socketTimeout = 60000
    clientConfiguration.maxConnections = 40

    // Create a S3 client
    val s3Client = AmazonS3Client(BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey), Region.getRegion(region), clientConfiguration)

    // Create a put object
    val por = PutObjectRequest(bucketName, file.name, file)
    s3Client.putObject(por)

    // Override the response headers
    val override = ResponseHeaderOverrides()
    override.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    // Generate the url request
    val urlRequest = GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, file.name)
    urlRequest.responseHeaders = override

    // Get the generated url
    val url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(urlRequest)
    return url.toString().replace("https://${bucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com/", distributionUrl)
}
```

Comment: In what way does it fail? Maybe try to only have one connection at a time such that at least that connecting can properly transfer data.

Comment: Try uploading a file using Postman first. Generate a Pre Signed URL --> Open Postman --> Make a POST request with the file attached using the presigned url. If that works, your code should work fine even in slow internet.

Comment: You should create some kind of task queue where you can upload files individually, and possibly consecutively rather than concurrently. Persist this task list so that you can retry failed uploads until they succeed. Also, why are you overriding the content type in the response? This suggests that you didn't set the content type correctly on the upload, which you should fix.